# I'm writing a DNS client but RDLENGTH returns 0

Tags: dns

The response is coming in as expected, no errors on `RCODE`, `QDCOUNT` is 1 and `ANCOUNT` is 1 as well.

When I check for `RDLENGTH` it's always 0. Forcefully reading `RDATA` I'm able to get what would be that IPv4 address I want except that it's partially correct. I got something like `xx.yy.zz.ww` where xx and yy is right but zz and ww is not. Would that be due to data compression or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've the issue myself. It stood out that I was fetching answer's `TTL` as an uint16 where it should be uint32. Fixing it did the trick and I'm now getting the correct ip address.